# how to block via .htaccess php files from sending any data to a specific IP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php based web application which might be sending data to an external IP. Is it possible to block php files, entire folder from sending any sort of data to the IP by specifying that IP in .htaccess ?

Comment: I don't think so. But I have the impression that if you explain why you think you need so we might find a better solution.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - Those links are about *incoming* traffic.

Comment: `.htaccess` has no effect on outgoing connections. I guess that threw me off. In that case: No, and .. _what_?